# Submitting a Form using a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, button, submit

I am doing validation using regular expressions and depending on what button is click there is certain validations done. I get the validation to work properly, but I cannot get the form to submit. Any suggestions would be appreciated here are some pieces to my code, I am fairly new to JS so any suggestions on how to make the code better would be great!

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" 
 action="results.php">
<table><tr>
<td> <input id="Search" type="button" onclick="checkWhichValidationIsNeeded(this.id);" value="search" 
name="action"/> </td>
</tr></table>
</form>

<script>
function checkWhichValidationIsNeeded(id){

  switch(id){
    case "Search":
          if (!validateName()) {
             return false;
          } else {
             document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
          }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Start with valid HTML: a TD must be a child of a TR, which must be in a TBODY, which must be in a TABLE. An input type button is not a submit button, make it type submit. Put the function on the form's submit listener so regardless of how the form is submitted, it gets called.

Comment: add return false; after  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();

Comment: RobG when I add the type 'submit' to the input type it submits the form regardless of the validation, so I added the document.getElementById() and used the .submit() function but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What does the function validateName do? If the function validateName returns a truthy value, the form should get submitted.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? As in press F12, click the button, check the console for errors and correct them? The HTML may be bad, but it was javascript errors that prevented the code working for me.